# Exchange 2010 - Remove AD User, Keep Email

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

We have a normal active directory user synchronized with an exchange mailbox.  Is there anyway to keep the mailbox & all the email, but remove the active directory account, or prevent the active directory account from logging into a machine?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable (not delete) the AD account... That will still allow mailbox access and the data to flow, but prevent AD logins.

or you can just change the account's password...